# Function not excuting after few executions

Tags: javascript, html

i'm writing a little website.
here is a part of the html code.

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="chapter-info"></div>
</div>

<audio src="" hidden></audio>
       
<div class="left-pane">
  <ol>
    <li> <a href="files/0/001.html">chapter1</a></li>
    <li> <a href="files/0/002.html">chapter2</a></li>
    <li> <a href="files/0/003.html">chapter3</a></li>
    .                                               .           
    .                                               .
    .                                               .
    <li> <a href="files/0/114.html"> chapter4</a></li>
  </ol>
 </div>
```

here is a js script.

```js
for (k = 0; k < 114; k++) {
    $(".chapter")[k].onclick = function() {
        $(".chapter-info").innerHTML = this.href.slice(-8, -5); alert($(".chapter-info").innerHTML); read();

    }
}
function read() {
    n = $(".chapter-info").innerHTML;
    if ($("#lock").src.match("padlock-off")) {
        if ($(".lang").selectedIndex != 0) {
            $("audio").src = "files/" + $(".lang").selectedIndex + "/" + n + ".mp3"; $("audio").load();
        }
        else {
            $("audio").src = "files/" + $(".lang").selectedIndex + "/" + $("#reciter").selectedIndex + "/" + n + ".mp3"; $("audio").load();
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that after a few clicks on a .chapter elements, the `$(".chapter-info") =  this.href.slice(-8,-5)` does no longer work. 
for info, the `.chapter` elements are anchors. i'm using javascript .the $() is a function i defined to ease programming. here is it.

```js
function $(x) {
    switch (document.querySelectorAll(x).length) {
        case 0: console.log("Element" + x + "has not been found"); return false; break;
        case 1: return document.querySelector(x); break;
        default: return document.querySelectorAll(x); break;
    }
}
```

Any help is welcome. thank you!!

Comment: Side comment: your `$` function returns different types based on its argument. That's really difficult to reason about.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? Your loop will stop looping if your code throws an error.

Comment: You need to include the html that's being used as I've recreated the html based off your code and due to that, I ran into no real issues like what you've got.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've found the problem. I noticed in the console error `17:39:25.969 TypeError: Value being assigned to HTMLProgressElement.value is not a finite floating-point value.
 js.js:96:27`
the problem above happens exactly when this error appears in the console. the progress element was used to simulate an audio progress. i don't why this error is returned but i simply removed the progress element. Thank you very much for your helps!! they were very helpful for me.

Comment: @Youssouf Always propose the question at the top of the page. Do not show your work first and then ask the question. This will cause some users to read the code again, whereas they may have known what to look for and may have seen it the first time around.